# Count how many times a field shows up in a collection while keeping all data with no duplicates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Let's say I have a collection like this:

```
{
  _id : 544e97123c9ef694fc68e21b,
  title: "First Title",
  notebook: {
    title: "Misc",
    slug: "misc"
  }
}
{
  _id: 54ab035a849788d0921d8eb2,
  title: "Second Title",
  notebook: {
    title: "Personal",
    slug: "personal"
  }
}
{
  _id: 544e97123c9ef694fc68e21b,
  title: "Third Title",
  notebook: {
    title: "Misc",
    slug: "misc"
  }
}
```

In my view I want to be able to show how many times a notebook title has been used along with a link to that particular notebook's slug in no particular order. For example:

```
<a href="/notebooks/misc">Misc(2)</a>
<a href="/notebooks/personal">Personal(1)</a>
```

I have achieved this by going through each document but the problem is that it has duplicates because it is going through each document. So in my view it looks like this:

```
<a href="/notebooks/misc">Misc(2)</a>
<a href="/notebooks/personal">Personal(1)</a>
<a href="/notebooks/misc">Misc(2)</a>
```

How can I grab the notebook.title, notebook.slug, count them, and have no duplicates?

This is my current hacky way of doing this (this results in duplicates):

```
function countNotebooks(notes) {
  var table = Object.create(null);
  for (var i = 0; i < notes.length; i++) {
    if (typeof table[notes[i].notebook.slug] === 'undefined') {
      table[notes[i].notebook.slug] = 1;
    } else {
      table[notes[i].notebook.slug] += 1;
    }
  }
  return table;
}

app.get('/notebooks', function(req, res) {
  Note.find(function(err, notes) {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    }
    res.render('notebooks/index.html', {
      title: 'All Notebooks',
      jumbotron: 'Notebooks',
      notes: notes,
      notesTable: countNotebooks(notes)
    });
  });
});
```

notebooks/index.html:

```
{% for note in notes %}
  <article class="note">
    <h3 class="note-title">
      <a href="/notebooks/{{ note.notebook.slug }}">{{ note.notebook.title }}</a> <span class="count">({{ notesTable[note.notebook.slug] }})</span>
    </h3>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by essentially grouping the data based on your common key. The [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) of MongoDB is designed for this sort of aggregation and manipulation.

First though, can I correct your data sample since you have a duplicate `_id` value, which is not allowed.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544e97123c9ef694fc68e21b"),
    "title" : "First Title",
    "notebook" : {
            "title" : "Misc",
            "slug" : "misc"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ab035a849788d0921d8eb2"),
    "title" : "Second Title",
    "notebook" : {
            "title" : "Personal",
            "slug" : "personal"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ac074fa8a621d3fd49ac91"),
    "title" : "Third Title",
    "notebook" : {
            "title" : "Misc",
            "slug" : "misc"
    }
}
```

To add the "count" values for the "slug" occurances in the data you can form a pipeline like this:

```
Note.aggregate([

    // Group on the slug values and put other fields in an array
    { "$group": {
         "_id": "$notebook.slug",
         "count": { "$sum": 1 },
         "docs": { 
             "$push": {
                 "_id": "$_id",
                 "title": "$title",
                 "notebook": "$notebook"
             }
         }
    }},

    // Unwind the created array elements
    { "$unwind": "$docs" },

    // Re-structure back to original form
    { "$project": {
        "_id": "$docs._id",
        "title": "$docs.title",
        "count": "$count",
        "notebook": "$docs.notebook"
    }},

    // Sort in original order (or as desired)
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1 } }

],function(err,result) {

});
```

And what that will give you is results like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("544e97123c9ef694fc68e21b"),
    "count" : 2,
    "title" : "First Title",
    "notebook" : {
            "title" : "Misc",
            "slug" : "misc"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ab035a849788d0921d8eb2"),
    "count" : 1,
    "title" : "Second Title",
    "notebook" : {
            "title" : "Personal",
            "slug" : "personal"
    }
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54ac074fa8a621d3fd49ac91"),
    "count" : 2,
    "title" : "Third Title",
    "notebook" : {
            "title" : "Misc",
            "slug" : "misc"
    }
}
```

That's if you want to "retain the documents", but if you just want the unique "slugs" like a "facet count", then just use The first **`$group`** with **`$first`** on the notebook title rather than **`$push`** with the other content:

```
Note.aggregate([

    // Group on the slug values and put other fields in an array
    { "$group": {
         "_id": "$notebook.slug",
         "count": { "$sum": 1 },
         "title": { "$first": "$notebook.title" }
    }},
],function(err,result) {

});
```

It should be fairly self explanatory but just to summarize. The initial [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is done using the value of "slug" to count the occurrences using the [**`$sum`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator. In order to keep the rest of the document data it is placed in an array under the "slug" using [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/).

After grouping the array is de-normalized to documents using **`$unwind`**, then simply re-structured back to original form using [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). The final [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/) operation provides the original order or whatever you want, since the ordering was changed during the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) pipeline stage.

Not only does this get the result, but it would allow you to "page" the data using [**`$limit`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) and [**`$skip`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) operators with the count values in place, and even sort the data based on those count values if needed.

Take a look at the full a[ggregation pipeline operator reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) for full descriptions and other things that can be done here.

Comment: I think the output still is not useful for the OP, since iterating it would give three `hrefs` elements, two in them being duplicates?

Comment: @BatScream Which if you read the OP's question (and the title) that is what they asked for.

Comment: Hmm..yes, the title says so, just wrote down a solution based on his code and his output, in case it is that what he wants(by the code that he has shown).

Comment: Thank you to both of you. Very clever and insightful. My title was misleading, by keeping all data I meant I wanted to keep slug, title, and count. I was running a mongo query with .distinct() but it was only returning the item I was running distinct() on so I wanted to mention I wanted other fields included. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

- `Group` by `notebook.slug` and the `notebook.title` fields, to
  eliminate duplicates.
- Since the order of display is not important, you could skip the `sort` stage here.
- `Project` them.

Code:

```
Model.aggregate([
{$group:{"_id":{"title":"$notebook.title",
                "slug":"$notebook.slug"},
                "count":{$sum:1}}},
{$project:{"title":"$_id.title",
           "slug":"$_id.slug",
           "count":1,"_id":0}}
],function(err,data){
      // handle response and store it in the `notes` variable to be
      // used to display.
  })
```

o/p:

```
{ "count" : 1, "title" : "Personal", "slug" : "personal" }
{ "count" : 2, "title" : "Misc", "slug" : "misc" }
```

And display as,

```
{% for note in notes %}
  <article class="note">
    <h3 class="note-title">
      <a href="/notebooks/{{ note.slug }}">{{ note.title }}</a> 
        <span class="count">({{note.count}})</span>
    </h3>
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```